# R Studio using dplyr to summarize (where like)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to output the number of status (that is open) group by ID. Please see below example:
(note: (1 status that is open) is used to show why it's 1, I don't want to output the sentence)

[image]

Re-producible code:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
Status <- c("status.open","status.closed", "status.wait", "status.open", "status.open", "status.wait"  )
df <- data.frame(ID, Status)
```

pseudo-code:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(count = length(Status where status like "%open"))
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: "R Studio" is an integrated development environment (IDE) in which you use (a.o) R. This is not relevant in your question or title of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution (as close as possible to your 'pseudo-code') using `dplyr` and `grepl` and R's implicit conversion of booleans (where `TRUE` becomes 1 if we try to to math with it):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(grepl("open", Status)))
```

Returns:

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 2
>      ID count
>   <dbl> <int>
> 1     1     1
> 2     2     2
> ```

Comment: I'd hope all the suggested solutions work ;) But it's a matter of style and different approaches

Answer (score 3):

You may achieve this with the following code:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>%  filter(Status == "status.open") %>%   ## you only want status.open
  count(ID)                                   ## count members of ID
```

Which produces:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     1
2     2     2
```

Comment: Upvote but `count(ID)` is enough, no need for `group_by`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you for your improvement comment. I changed the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly like SQL-%open is:

```
library(stringr)

df %>%
  filter(str_detect(Status, "open$")) # open$ = ends with open
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution :

```
df %>% dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% dplyr::summarize(count = sum(Status == "status.open"))
```